# Using the matched wildcards in cmd

Tags: cmd, command-line, wildcard

Can we access the matched character in wildcards? 
I have some files in my current directory name as Lab***x***.pdsprj and I want to copy them to a subfolder in the same directory based on their file names such that *"Lab3.pdsprj"* goes to the subfolder *".//subfolder_name//lab3"* as  *".//subfolder_name//lab3//Lab3.pdsprj"*

I was trying something like

```
copy Lab?.pdsprj .//subfolder_name//lab(something here to access the matched number)
```

Its not necessary to use the above command only, any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not programming and it's not clear to me it's development, and Windows pathnames do not use `//` as a separator, but if the original casing (`Lab3` not `lab3`) is okay: `for %f in (Lab?.pdsprj) do copy %f .\subfolder\%~nf\%f` if interactive; double each percent sign if in a 'bat' script.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 if use "\" I am unable to use the tab-path autocomplete feature while "//" allows to do the same. For the question, can you tell a way to rename all the directories so that casing is not the problem. I tried "rename lab? Lab?" but it doesn't seem to work for directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem excessive if your requirement is not to have a case difference in the filename "Lab*" and the subdirectory "lab" as indicated by @dave_thompson_085. Although, that solution presumes that the "lab*" subdirectory already exists. I could be changed to do this.

```
FOR %%A IN (Lab?.pdsprj) DO (
    MKDIR "%%~nA"
    COPY %%A .\subfolder\%%~nA\%%~nxA
)
```

If there must be a case difference, this could be used. This will run on a `windows` `command-line` `batch-file` running under `cmd`. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell was installed with it on the system.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "C:\src\t\Do-CopyPdsprjFiles.ps1"
```

=== C:\src\t\Do-CopyPdsprjFiles.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 'Lab*.pdsprj' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.Name -match 'Lab(\d+).pdsprj') {
            $LabNumber = $Matches[1]
            $LabDir = Join-Path -Path '.' -ChildPath "lab$($LabNumber)"
            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $LabDir)) { mkdir $Labdir | Out-Null }
            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $LabDir
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although I don't know powershell but I am able to understand your code a little bit. But still it seems little excessive. Instead, I was thinking to rename directories to make the names in  same case and renaming them again. I tried using "rename lab? Lab?" but it doesn't seem to work on directories, although a similar command worked for files. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: If you want the same case, then the first FOR loop code should work. Did you try it?

Comment: to convert the names of directory to same case I was using 'rename lab? Lab?' but it doesn't work, while a similar thing works on files. Can you suggest something on that?

Comment: I found out why [here](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html). So wildcards are not supported for directories. Guess then we cannot do more than your answer in cmd and a little learning about powershell will be helpful.

Comment: @Dhruv, that was not part of the original question. Please do some research, then ask a new question if needed.